# Domain Name Re-resolution issue Firefox

Tags: selenium, amazon-web-services, tcp, dns, amazon-route53

If I have four identical servers hosted on AWS EC2, divided into two groups and the each group is located in different AWS regions. There is one ELB in front of each group. I configured two weighted alias records (not latency based) point to the ELB of each group in the AWS Route53.

Each server has a simple `apache2` server installed which display a simple page with different words to distinguish from each other. I started a browser client (made by [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) library) frequently reloading page with the URL which is the domain name of these servers (pause for 1 seconds) but I found that that the browser (`firefox`) always return pages from servers in one group instead of returning pages from both group in 50% times as how [Weighted Round Robin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted) works.
I also found that if I pause for a relatively longer time, pages from the other group do get returned but as long as I refresh the page frequently. It never changes. Request always hits one group not the other.

I also wrote a simple `Java` program to keep querying the domain name from AWS Route 53 and the address I got back does change between two group, but the browser seems stuck in the connection with the group it first connected (as long as I frequently refresh)

I suspect it is the problem of TCP connection still alive, but I am not sure. BTW, I have already disabled browser cache and I am using Mac OS X 10.9. (This does happen on Ubuntu as well)

Any ideas will be really appreciated. This issue is really important to my works the deadline of which is approaching. Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's normal.

Many, perhaps most, browsers cache the dns response they get from the OS, and the timing of this cache is unrelated to the DNS TTL -- it's at the discretion of the browser developers.

For Firefox, the time by default appears to be 60 seconds, so, not likely to be directly related to keepalives, though there's certainly some potential for that, too... albeit for a shorter time interval, in some cases, since many servers will tear down an idle kept-alive connection before 60 seconds, since a connection idle for so long is a potentially expensive waste of a resource.

Firefox: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration

For a discussion of the issue and observations made of the behavior of different browsers, see also: http://dyn.com/blog/web-browser-dns-caching-bad-thing/

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, but I set both the Network.dnsCacheExpiration and Network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod to 0 on both the firefox I am using on my laptop and the the browser started by the Selenium library. Nothing helped. There seems to be a bug for Firefox version below 29 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=861273)

Comment: It very well may be a bug, but to confirm... you did use `network` in lower case, not `Network`, right?  Also, did you confirm that a value of "0" doesn't mean indefinite (try really small values)?  You could confirm keepalive timing behavior using `tshark`.  All of this leaves me a little confused as to what you're looking for in an answer.  This is the status quo: (W)RR DNS cannot reliably provide quick failover to all individual users who are already active on the site.  Even if it's a bug or poor default config, we (web platform admins) can't (usually) fix or mandate browser config.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the comments. Yes, I copied the configuration name from firefox about:config page, so it shouldn't be spelling error in my code and setting it to 0 is indeed the way to disable DNS cache of firefox as suggested by people on the Internet. What I want to achieve is to simulate website browsing behavior of users (or keep accessing a website with same URL) and i want to see that the user requests being routed to the 2 group of servers I have equal amount of times given a longer period of monitoring.

Comment: For some reason as I frequently accessing the URL I always get response from one (group of) server(s) not the other.  I want to know what could possibly being the reason. I am not trying to achieve failover but distributing user requests.

Comment: Anyway, subtle problems are always hard to resolve just by describing the situation. So thanks again for your patient considering my question. Just one more question, if you don't mind: Ideally, even if the browser or the OS caching DNS response, the effect of this caching is that the user request distribution achieved via WRR DNS load balancing will be reflected for longer period of time in stead of immediate effect if no caching at all ? Correct ?